# Is the unit of maximum image uploaded on the laravel rules?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, image-uploading, rules

My rules in laravel is like this :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'photo'=> 'required|mimes:jpeg,gif,png,jpg|max:5120',
    ];
}
```

After I read some references, I concluded that max:5120 is maximum 5 MB

When I upload a image with 1.05 MB and jpg type, it can be saved

But when I upload a image with 2.36 MB and jpg type, it can not be saved

Whereas maximum image that can be uploaded is 5MB

Why it can not be saved?

Is max:5120 != max:5MB?

Comment: Your problem might be php.ini settings.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunoi, Seems it's not because of the settings in php.ini. In my php.ini : upload_max_filesize=2M & post_max_size=8M

Comment: Why this question is downvote?

Comment: php.ini is exactly the problem. Max filesize is 2MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` and `size` rules define the size of the files in kilobytes (KB). Also your issue is related to the php config which limits the maximum upload size to 2MB by default. For which you need to make the following changes in your `php.ini` file

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 10M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```

Comment: I had set it. But when I upload image with 2.36 MB, Then I save it, there exist error : `This page isn’t working

myshop.dev is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`. In addition, the image can not be displayed. Whereas, the image was stored in a folder

Comment: @TrendingNews have you tried restarting the server after making the changes?

Comment: I had restart the server. But it's the same

Comment: Check your error log to see what exactly the issue is. Try enabling app debug. Check the size of the image stored even after error message. See if its the same size as original or it's below 2MB.

Comment: @TrendingNews this is totally irrelevant to this question. Let's continue the discussion in your other question. I have answered this and this one is solved. Post your resize_image function in the other question.